# Xcuitest - How can I wait until image finished to load

Tags: swift, coded-ui-tests, xcuitest

I'm running my UiTests on app that uses images/videos from the camera roll/Google photos/Etc..

All the images/videos are in CollectionView and each asset is in a specific cell.

When the app opens the "footage screen" it contains 15 assets at the same time and I'm trying to create a function that waits until all of the images finish to load.

Why do I need it:
I have tests that select images/videos and sometimes the Xctest could select the first one because not all of the assets finish loading.

Note:
I don't have any indication that tells me "all the assets finish to load".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should inspect your `app.debugDescription` before and after loading. Find anything that you can asynchronously verify.
- If necessary, add accessibility identifiers into app code, that are different before/after loading. You should also add some accessibility labels to help VoiceOver and VoiceControl users to interact with your app.
- You can use SUITCase for screenshot testing and awaits.
  https://github.com/devexperts/suitcase/
- You can add some EarlGrey 2 asserts. This testing framework is a little bit more flexible and automatically await async operations. The good thing is you can use it alongside existing XCTest tests.
- Finally, you can just `sleep(5)` :D

Answer (score 3):

There is **expectation** method in **XCTest** framework to test asynchronous work.

### [expectation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/1500899-expectation)

> Use this method to create XCTestExpectation instances that can be fulfilled when asynchronous tasks in your tests complete.

You can create a function for the use of existence prediction like below:

```
// create a function to wait for prediction
func waitNotExistance(for element: XCUIElement, timeout: Double = 5) {
    let notExists = NSPredicate(format: "exists != 1")
    let elementShown = expectation(for: notExists, evaluatedWith: element)
    wait(for: [elementShown], timeout: timeout, enforceOrder: false)
}
```

Assume that you set `accessibilityIdentifier` "*loading*" as initial value and "*loaded*" after completion. You can wait until non-existence for them.

**Usage**:

```
// your loading cell
let ladingElement = app.collectionViews.element(boundBy: 0).cells.matching(identifier: "loading").element

// wait until timeout reached 
waitNotExistance(for: ladingElement)

// assert here what you expect..
```

Answer (score 0):

The second suggestion resolve the problem,

I've added an accessibility identifiers to the cells that containing the images
1: When the image is still loading "selectFootageCellImageEmpty"
2. When the image finishes loading "selectFootageCellImageLoaded"
And now I wait until there is no "selectFootageCellImageEmpty" in the screen for example:

```
        let endOfLoop = Date().addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(10))
        while app.collectionViews.element(boundBy: 2).cells.matching(identifier: "selectFootageCellImageEmpty").element.exists {
        sleep(1)
        print("Waiting for all images to finish loading")
        if Date() > endOfLoop {
            break
        }
    }
```

- I could add an XCTAssert instead of the "break" line but I don't need it at the moment.

Comment: It is better to use `timeout` instead of `sleep`. I add an answer regarding to that.